# Ubuntu 18.04 install for remote server

Tags: 18.04

Does anyone know of an ISO image for Ubuntu 18.04 that will allow me to install it on a remote server? I'm trying to get a server up and running for my friend so he can use it for minecraft gaming but some of the mods he needs wont run on later versions of ubuntu and the hosting company wont help. The only options given on his hosting admin page is the ISO URL (I can host that if needed) the MD5 checksum info and thats it.

So I need an image that will install without any input and then start with SSH ready and live so the server can be accessed via SSH using putty from his Windows PC at home.
I'm not sure if this is possible as I assume a pre-loaded root/password will need to be done then I can change the password via SSH.

Can anyone help? I've never tackled anything like this before and google brings up so many results its confusing, lol...

Thank you inadvance

Comment: Do they just want an installer image? Or do they want you to upload a bootable already installed system ISO? Usually it is the first one, and you'd just upload Ubuntu 18.04 Server. But... why won't the mod work on a recent (20.04 LTS) version of Ubuntu? Assuming you installed the correct Java version, I don't think it should depend on the Ubuntu version.

Comment: Hi it needs to bootable already installed system ISO please. This way it can be accessed via SSH, then the root password can be changed but the server fully ready to use. 
As for the mod's, some of the ones he's using have not been updated and only work on 18.04 as he's tried with a 20.04 system and they error out. I'm not sure why as I've never played minecraft.